# Search chinese words in MySQL with rlike with boundaries

Tags: mysql, regex, utf-8

I need to search rows with the searched words, but somehow rlike is not working with Chinese (and UTF-8) characters. Here is the one I am trying:

```
select * from mytable where mycolumn rlike '[[:<:]]健康早餐[[:>:]]';
```

but this works only with English characters not with UTF-8 characters. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Why down vote for this old question, any reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default MySQL uses the ISO-8859-1 (Latin1) character set. configure your char set with gbk for native Chinese.check whether your DB is configured to handle chinese characters. RLIKE is likely to produce unexpected results with multi-byte char.
For Details refer [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: Yes, my database is utf-8 (table collation is utf8-general-ci)  and presently storing all characters in Chinese only (Joomla database). Just the search doesn't work.